# Kronos SaasHR Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, kronos-workforce-central

I am trying to utilize Kronos SaasHR WebServices through Visual Studio.  Has anyone successfully done any work with these services and are willing to share a little code.  Specifically I am having an issue passing login credentials to the service.  There is no description of it in their soap header. I believe the webservice is Java based. When I add the reference to VS, I get the WSDL as well as the .SOAP references, but I am having a problem getting past the authorization.

https://secure.entertimeonline.com/ta/ is the base address.

Any help would be appreciated...
David

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)